# I try to disable BJLL plugin on specific pages, but I have error

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, lazy-loading

I use [BJ Lazy Load](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bj-lazy-load/installation/) and I try to not load in a specific page.

But I have PHP error output.

I read "[Disable BJLL on specific pages/specific browsers](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/solution-disable-bjll-on-specific-pagesspecific-browsers)" (the topic is closed now) and I use:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($url,'portfolio') !== false) { // if it is portfolio
function remove_BJLL_script() {
    wp_deregister_script('BJLL');
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts','remove_BJLL_script');
function remove_BJLL_filter(){
    $bjll = BJLL::singleton();
    remove_filter('the_content',array($bjll, 'filter'),200);
}
add_filter('wp','remove_BJLL_filter');
}
```

and the output error that I receved is:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method BJLL::singleton() in /home/sergiopi/public_html/wp-content/themes/sp_320press/functions.php on line 1559`

Anybody knows why?

Thank you! :-)

Comment: I've downloaded the plugin and search for the term `singelton` - and it was found zero times. Looks like this code snippet isn't working anymore.

Comment: In your opinion, in its place, what would you put?